# I want to use $lookup function of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
product[{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5720cc7d6e589904b855cc12"), 
    "p_id" : "p0001", 
    "p_name" : "printed_pant", 
    "p_company" : "Hoffman", 
    "p_price" : 3677.0, 
    "p_color" : "charcol", 
    "p_size" : "XL", 
    "total_price" : 77217.0, 
    "total_sell" : NumberInt(21)
}]

branch[{ 
    "_id" : {
        "c_branch_id" : "b03", 
        "c_branch_location" : "Hydrabad", 
        "p_id" : "p0001",
        "p_name" : "kurty_pajam"
    }, 

    "total_item" : NumberInt(8)
}]
```

how can I use `$lookup` in the above mentioned collection?
where product is the leftcollection and branch is the rightcollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
db.product.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "branch",
          localField: "p_id",
          foreignField: "_id.p_id",
          as: "branch_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

Comment: @BiswajitMaity Here is why `foreignField: "_id. p_id"` (space)